# Validate Hash With Dynamic Keys

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm attempting to validate a hash object with dynamic keys, but consistent typed values. First off is there a simple way to do this in Mongoosejs (as in built in schema type)?

After reading most of the docs (or overlooking them) I proceeded under the assumption there was not using the custom validate SchemaType:

```
var _ = require('underscore/lodash');

function validValue( val ){
  return _.isString( val.name );
}

function myValidator( obj ){
  //assuming hash value
  var valid = true;

  _.each( value, function( val, key ){
    if( ! ((/supercoolkey/i).test( key ) && validValue( val )) )
      valid = false;
  });

  return valid;
}

var MySchema = new Schema({
  dynamicKeyHash: {type: Object, validate: [myValidator, 'Invalid hash object']}
});
```

If there is no easy way to test against dynamic keys built in, how can I make my validation correctly reject the saving of the object later on? Currently the MySchema model will save regardless of what the 'dynamicKeyHash' key contains as a value.